# Regex match only full word, but not if wrapped in quotes

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to match only the full word, but not if wrapped in quotes

for example: `word`

but not: `"word"`

The first can be matched with `/\bword\b/`

For the second this is the closest I've gotten, the problem is it prevents matches from
`"word` `word"` and `"word"`, I only want it not to match if it is `"word"`

```
(?!")\bword\b(?!")
```

Comment: A slightly different approach would be to match word with arbitrary characters on either side and then check for quotes in code. The advantage is that you'll remember what it does six months from now when you're not reading a diabolically clever but incomprehensible regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex in PHP:

```
"\w+"(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\w+\b
```

This will fail every `"word"` using `(*SKIP)(*F)` directives and will match each word otherwise.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oP3nL9/1)

Comment: This is more immediately understandable.

Answer (score 2):

```
\b(\w+(?!")|(?<!")\w+)\b
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/yM7fS7/3)

The idea is to match the word if it is not followed or preceded by `"` (using [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), not the two at the same time.

Comment: Explanation might help

Comment: This is clever, nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/((\")*word$)|(^word(\")*)/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/aG5dA8/1